# Can someone explain php comparison oddities

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Why this php code evals to true? Was thinking maybe some kind of casting, but can't find any related info. Any ideas?

`var_dump(5 < [6]);`

Comment: if you pass 4 instead of 6 still it gives true.

Comment: Because http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php where you can find a string `array is always greater`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php `array anything array is always greater `

Answer (score 3):

In php documentation on comparison operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php, in chapter **Comparison with Various Types**:

> array | anything | array is always greater

So, there is no casting. It's sort of hard-coded.